# Propiedad ORDER de flex no funciona

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Estoy intentado usar la propiedad order de flexbox y no se me activa. La estaba ocupando antes y si era posible usarla, revise mi codigo a ver si tengo un error de sintaxtis y no lo encuentro, tengo todos los items que quiero manejar con la propiedad order los tengo como hijos de un solo padre que se llama <div class="director-contenedor"

este es mi codigo

```css
/* 8= -------------------BENEFICIOS BOX------------------- */
.director-contenedor-beneficios {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 3rem auto 2rem auto;
}

.contenedor-item-texto {
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: row;
  order: -3;
}

/* 10=---------ITEMS RAPY CUADRADO TEXTO ---------+++END+++++++++*/

/*----- CONTENEDOR NUMERO 1---- */
.contenedor-beneficio-total {
  margin: 3.5rem auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 24rem;
  height: 410px;
  background: red;

  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}

/*----- CONTENEDOR NUMERO 2---- */
.contenedor-beneficio-total-dos {
  margin: 3.5rem auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 24rem;
  height: 410px;

  background: blue;
  order: -1;
}

/*----- CONTENEDOR NUMERO 3---- */
.contenedor-beneficio-total-tres {
  margin: 3.5rem auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 24rem;
  height: 410px;

  background: pink;
  order: -2;
}

/* 8= -------------------BENEFICIOS BOX------------++++END++++----- */

/* 9= ----------MINI ITEMS----------- */
.contenedor-mini-beneficios {
  background: orange;
  order: 3;
}

.box-mini-beneficios {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

/* 9=----------- MINI ITEMS --------++++END++++ */
```

```html
<div class="director-contenedor-beneficios">
    <div class="container-artisan">
        <div class="contenedor-beneficio-total">
            <div class="box-beneficio-total">
                <img src="estilos/imagenes/front/presente23.png" alt="" class="imagen-beneficio-total">
                <div class="contenedor-texto-beneficio">
                    <h4 class="titulo-beneficio-total">Express sin limites <span
                            class="cambio-color-beneficio"><br>Cobertura
                            total</span>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="parrafo-total">

                        <span class="titulo-parrafos uno-bene"><strong>Recolectores</strong> en todo el
                            pais</span><br>
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos dos-bene"><strong>Red comercios</strong> Express
                            para</span><span class="titulo-parrafos tres-bene"> entregas y retiros en <strong>todo
                                el
                                país</strong></span>
                        <br>
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos cuatro-bene"><strong>El cliente elige</strong> cuando,
                            donde</span><br>
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos cinco-bene">y como lo recibe</span>


                        <!-- <img class="img-contacto" src="estilos/imagenes/front/sms.png" alt=""><img class="img-contacto"
                        src="estilos/imagenes/front/whatsapp.png" alt=""><img class="img-contacto"
                        src="estilos/imagenes/front/facebook.png" alt=""><img class="img-contacto"
                        src="estilos/imagenes/front/correo-electronico.png" alt=""><img class="img-contacto"
                        src="estilos/imagenes/front/telefono.png" alt=""></li> -->

                    </div>
                    <div class="boton-beneficio">
                        Empezar
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-artisan">
        <div class="contenedor-mini-beneficios">
            <div class="box-mini-beneficios">
                <div class="imagen-mini-beneficios">
                    <i class="fas fa-truck img-bene"></i>
                </div>

                <!-- <p>texto beneficio</p> -->
            </div>

            <div class="box-mini-beneficios">
                <div class="imagen-mini-beneficios">
                    <i class="fas fa-tags img-bene"></i>
                </div>

                <!-- <p>texto beneficio</p> -->
            </div>
            <div class="box-mini-beneficios">
                <div class="imagen-mini-beneficios">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart img-bene"></i>
                </div>

                <!-- <p>texto beneficio</p> -->
            </div>
            <div class="box-mini-beneficios">
                <div class="imagen-mini-beneficios">
                    <i class="fas fa-globe img-bene"></i>
                </div>
                <!-- <p>texto beneficio</p> -->
            </div>
            <div class="box-mini-beneficios">
                <div class="imagen-mini-beneficios">
                    <i class="fas fa-money-bill img-bene"></i>
                </div>
                <!-- <p>texto beneficio</p> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-artisan">
        <div class="contenedor-beneficio-total-dos">
            <div class="box-beneficio-total">
                <img src="estilos/imagenes/front/waree.png" alt="" class="imagen-beneficio-total">
                <div class="contenedor-texto-beneficio">
                    <h4 class="titulo-beneficio-total">Asistencia y traslado <span
                            class="cambio-color-beneficio"><br>Full
                            stock</span>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="parrafo-total">
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos uno-bene"><strong>Logistica inversa y directa</strong> de
                            equipamientos de valor</span><br>
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos uno-bene"><strong>Stock</strong> en tiempo real</span><br><span
                            class="titulo-parrafos tres-bene"><strong>Administración</strong> y gestión en planta
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boton-beneficio">
                        Empezar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-artisan">
        <div class="contenedor-item-texto">

            <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
                <div class="box-item-texto">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">
                    <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
                    <p class="parrafo-en-texto">esta es al descripcion de lo que hacemos en este</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
                <div class="box-item-texto">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">
                    <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
                    <p class="parrafo-en-texto">te</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
                <div class="box-item-texto">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">
                    <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
                    <p class="parrafo-en-texto">esta es al descripcion de lo que hacemos en este</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-artisan">
        <div class="contenedor-beneficio-total-tres">
            <div class="box-beneficio-total">
                <img src="estilos/imagenes/front/waree.png" alt="" class="imagen-beneficio-total">
                <div class="contenedor-texto-beneficio">
                    <h4 class="titulo-beneficio-total">Asistencia y traslado <span class="cambio-color-beneficio"><br>
                            Full
                            stock</span>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="parrafo-total">
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos uno-bene"><strong>Logistica equipamientos de valor</span><br>
                        <span class="titulo-parrafos uno-bene"><strong>Stock</strong> en til</span><br><span
                            class="titulo-parrafos tres-bene"><strong>Administración</strong> y gestión en planta
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boton-beneficio">
                        Empezar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No obtengo ningun movimiento por parte del order. todos son hijos de div.director-contenedor. Aclaro que antes si podia moverlo con el order, he revisado errores de sintaxis en el codigo html para ver si se me ha quedado por fuera algun elemento pero lo tengo todo bien encerrado con su padre. Asi que, les agradeceria algun consejo de si les has ocurrido algo similar.

Comment: La propiedad `order` se aplica a los elementos dentro de un contenedor flex, no al contenedor en si. Puedes revisar que el contenedor padre tenga display:flex para que funcione.

Comment: Si, lo tiene. El contenedor es <div class="director-contenedor-beneficios" > y tiene display:flex. Que raro este percance

Comment: Incluso, compruevo que <div class="director-contenedor-beneficios" > tiene flex. con flex-direction row y column, y me mueve todos los elementos debidamente. Pero al querer moverlos con order no le aplica

Comment: Existe un contenedor intermedio con `class='container-artisan'` que hace que order no tenga efecto (hay un solo elemento dentro). La propiedad order deberia aplicarse a ese nivel para ordenar los contenedores.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad order de flexbox solo funciona si el contenedor padre tiene como display:flex;

creo que te está fallando la ubicación de la clase contenedor-item-texto, que es a la que has colocado la propiedad ORDER, prueba esto:

```
<div class="container-artisan contenedor-item-texto">

    <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
        <div class="box-item-texto">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">


            <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
            <p class="parrafo-en-texto">esta es al descripcion de lo que hacemos en este</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
        <div class="box-item-texto">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">


            <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
            <p class="parrafo-en-texto">te</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-contenedor-item-texto">
        <div class="box-item-texto">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="box-titulo-parrafo">


            <h3 class="texto-item">Ahorra tiempo</h3>
            <p class="parrafo-en-texto">esta es al descripcion de lo que hacemos en este</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Básicamente subi un nivel la clase en cuestión y eliminé un div, ahora te toca revisar si tienes que recalcular algun css correspondiente a ese div.

Veo que tienes mucho CSS repetido, trata de usar una clase general para los contenedores con propiedades idénticas.